# Killing all processes, force everything to stop

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe, jpanel

I have a game that runs off of `JPanel` which has on it many other things which have their own independent timers and such. It seems that when I try to remove the panel from my frame to replace it with another `JPanel` it refuses to actually end all of its own processes. So even if I am able to remove it from the screen of the panel by removing it and setting it `null`, its processes are still going off in the background, IE the music and the stuff flying around.

What i need to know is some solution as to how to completely kill this `JPanel` and terminate its life to its entirety.

Seems not many people have run into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having that issue in my own game..

Simply create some custom method i.e `destroy()` which will stop all timers gameloops music etc.

i.e

```
MyPanel panel=new MyPanel();

...

panel.destory();//stop music, timers etc

frame.remove(panel);

//refresh frame to show changes
frame.revalidate(); 
frame.repaint();
```

where panel would be:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private Timer t1,t2...;

    //this method will terminate the game i.e timers gameloop music etc
    void destroy() {
       t1.stop();
       t2.stop();
    }

}
```

**Alternatively** you could make your Swing Timers *observers* of sorts by making it check each time whether the panel is visible and if not it should stop executing. This would though now of course cause you to create a timer which will only start the others once the panel becomes visible:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private Timer t1,t2,startingTimer;

    MyPanel() {
       t1=new Timer(60,new AbstractAction() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               if(!MyPanel.this.isVisible()) {//if the panel is not visible
                   ((Timer)(ae.getSource())).stop();
               }
           }
       });
       startingTimer=new Timer(100,new AbstractAction() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               if(MyPanel.this.isVisible()) {//if the panel is visible
                   t1.start();//start the timers
                   t2.start();
                   ((Timer)(ae.getSource())).stop();//dont forget we must stop this timer now

               }
           }
       });
       startingTimer.start();//start the timer which will check when panel becomes visible and start the others as necessary
    }

}
```

now all you would do is:

```
frame.remove(panel);//JPanel timers should also see panel is no more visible and timer will stop

//refresh frame to show changes 
frame.revalidate(); 
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: `Thread.stop()` has been deprecated.  It's also not thread-safe to call methods on components like `Component.isVisible()` on any thread other than the GUI thread.  If you're going to check a boolean shared between threads, make sure it's declared `volatile`.

Comment: @NovaDenizen I never used a Thread. Also Because its a Swing Timer i make use of the action which is processed on edt so in the code I illustrated there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myFrame.getContentPane().remove(myPanel);
            myFrame.validate();
```

Make sure your music and other components are within the panel so they are removed as well.

Comment: yea, i have tried this, and just tried again, the remove(); stand alone does not work ether. 
i also tryed myPanel=null;myFrame.remove(myPanel); myFrame.revalidate(); myFrame.repaint(); when i do this it at least removed panel from frame but music and hit detection and stuff still keeps processing. i was contemplating actually going through and making a master stop method for all my objects which stops all active timers, but its a lot of work and i am afraid that it would be time wasted if it does not work.

Comment: IMO you should be calling `repaint()` after `validate()` or else changes might not be reflected. ANd at that I prefer `revalidate()` as its for reflecting changes on both added or removed components